# $<char> in string is interpreted as variable...how to circumvent?

Tags: php, arrays

Consider the following file (slang.txt):

```
$#!+  -   excrement
$$  -   money
$46  -   money for snusnu
$h!t  -   excrement
$xy  -   sexy
/.  -   Slashdot
*4u  -   Kiss for you
*67  -   unknown
*eg*  -   evil grin
07734  -   hello
```

I want to put these terms into a database. For this, I first have to split the text into key-value pairs which are cleaned up. For this, I copied the contents of slang.txt to a php file:

```
$string = "$#!+  -   excrement
$$  -   money
$46  -   money for snusnu
$h!t  -   excrement
$xy  -   sexy
/.  -   Slashdot
*4u  -   Kiss for you
*67  -   unknown
*eg*  -   evil grin
07734  -   hello";

$list = explode("\n", $string);

foreach ($list as $item) {
  $pair = explode('-', $item);
  $result[trim($pair[0])] = trim($pair[1]);
}

print_r($result);
```

The result is almost there:

```
Array
(
    [$#!+] => excrement
    [$$] => money
    [$46] => money for snusnu
    [!t] => excrement
    [] => sexy
    [/.] => Slashdot
    [*4u] => Kiss for you
    [*67] => unknown
    [*eg*] => evil grin
    [07734] => hello
)
```

Problem: the "$" terms (such as $h in $h!t and $xy) are interpreted as variables and therefore not copied to the array see: [!t] => shit and [] => sexy instead of [$h!t] => shit and [$xy] => sexy. How can I resolve this?

P.S. The actual file is much, much larger, so I really can't go over the contents and escape all $'s or something, nor put the string between single brackets (because that would break the string when there are (and there are) words being used which contain an apastrophe :)

Comment: You could have provided a more family-friendly example...

Comment: I find the manual pretty talkative about this and related things here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php - @BoltClock: Sex per definition is family friendly.

Comment: Yeesh... not going to clean up all the answers as well. At least the question's been cleaned a little.

Comment: @BoltClock The number of children on StackOverflow is probably neglectable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of just using single quotes it would be even better to use NOWDOC. In that case you don't have to do any escaping at all, even if your strings contained `'` - and the first and last line are easier to read.

```
$string = <<<'END'
$#!+  -   shit
$$  -   money
$46  -   money for sex
$h!t  -   shit
$xy  -   sexy
/.  -   Slashdot
*4u  -   Kiss for you
*67  -   unknown
*eg*  -   evil grin
07734  -   hello
END;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use single quotes for the string:

```
$string = '$#!+  -   shit
$$  -   money
$46  -   money for sex
$h!t  -   shit
$xy  -   sexy
/.  -   Slashdot
*4u  -   Kiss for you
*67  -   unknown
*eg*  -   evil grin
07734  -   hello';
```

You will have to escape single quotes in the string, but those may be less common. If not, you'll have to escape the lot.

Or an even better solution: store this text in a separate file and read in in a string using `file` or `file_get_contents`.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to downvote, but while this does solve the problem it's not a good solution. What about educating the OP a bit?

Comment: What is not a good solution? The quick fix using single quotes, or the advise to put the data in a separate file?

Comment: Not a good solution = anything involving copy pasting the contents of a text file into PHP source only to process it further at runtime.

Comment: That's why I've suggested to put in in a separate file. You could put in in the source as an array already, but that means you're actually writing code when you want to extend the array. And anyway, I think every PHP programmer should know the difference between single and double quoted string, so even if single quotes aren't the best solution in this case, it would make not sense not to mention it here.

Comment: The fact remains that the current form of this answer suggests going with an approach that IMHO is no-hire material. It would be better for everyone to improve or expand the answer instead of having a discussion with me here :-)

Comment: I feel I've mentioned it enough, and you have pleaded for separate files already, by which you have earned my upvote. But the accepted answer shows how the OP feels about good solutions. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward answer would be to use a single-quoted string literal (or more conveniently [NOWDOC syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)).

But this is ignoring the fact that you are going about this in a *really really roundabout way*. Why move the file contents into a PHP variable when you can do

```
$list = file('slang.txt');
$result = array();

foreach ($list as $item) {
  $pair = explode('-', $item);
  $result[trim($pair[0])] = trim($pair[1]);
}

print_r($result);
```

If you are thinking that loading up an external file each time is undesirable, that's OK. *Why don't you write the array `$result` itself as a literal and save even more time?*

```
echo var_export($result); // and copy/paste this into your PHP source
```

Comment: I knew about HEREDOC, but not NOWDOC. I learned something today, for which I thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply defining the string using single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"` will prevent the `$`s from being interpreted as variables:

```
$string = '$#!+  -   shit
$$  -   money
$46   -   money for sex
$h!t  -   shit
$xy  -   sexy
/.  -   Slashdot
*4u  -   Kiss for you
*67  -   unknown
*eg*  -   evil grin
07734  -   hello';
```

Alternatively, you can backslash escape them `\$`: `"\$#!+ -..."`